# how to make a query to access a map that is inside an array in FireStore? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to perform query filtering on values ​​of a map nested inside an array field?

[image]

```
const empleado = collection(db, "empleados");

const q = query(empleado, where('solicitudAusencia', 'array-contains',''))onSnapshot(q,(snapshot)=>{
let empleados=[]
let total=[]
snapshot.forEach(doc=>{
    empleados.push({...doc.data()})
})
console.log(empleados)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to perform a query filtering on values from a map nested inside an array field?  It's not clear what exactly you are trying to accomplish or where you are stuck.  Please edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: yes sir, that is my question.

Comment: Its not possible in Firestore.  You will have to change your schema to make it possible.

Comment: could I access the map in general? and filter the fields in my code?

Comment: Sure, you can do whatever you want with the data in your own code.  But Firestore can't query map fields in arrays directly.